# Why Pymesh boolean operations extremely slow with my simple geometry setup?

Tags: python, c++, boolean-operations, csg, pymesh

I am testing the efficiency of boolean operations in pymesh to see how fast it calculate boolean. But the performance I got using the default engine was extremely slow, comparing to the [libigl paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/mesh-arrangements/mesh-arrangements-for-solid-geometry-siggraph-2016-zhou-et-al.pdf)

> 0.25 s in calculating self-union of 8616 meshes.

I did an experiment with a grain mesh intersecting with a small primitive box. *The grain has 12 vertices, the primitive box has 8 vertices. The position of the grain is just semi-above one of the box's face. Calculating the intersection of these two objects, took 0.036 seconds.*

**For such an easy calculation, why it takes 0.036 seconds?** When conducting this boolean operation, pymesh us Libigl as an engine, which is written in C++. **DO I have to write the code in C++ to use Libigl directly to get similar performance?**

These results are produced in the following environment:

- Processor: 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- Memory: 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- OS: Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7
- IDE: Visual Studio Code, Jupyter Notebook
- Python version: 3.7.5
- Pymesh version: pymesh2==0.3

Answer (score 0):

PyMesh describes itself as a *rapid prototyping library* and it depends on many other libraries.

If you want to use directly *libigl* from Python you may wish to try their [Python bindings](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/).

In either case, make sure you measure your program's speed using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.